# Is there a way to make a plotly plot that just displays text?

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am creating a dash-app, that makes some callbacks until it finally draws a 3D-scatter-plot. This takes about one or two seconds. I would like to know if there is a way to make a plot in the beginning that just contains text (something like "Plot is being computed. This can take some seconds.").

So far I am doing something like

```
    dcc.Graph(
        id='scatter_plot',
        figure=px.scatter_3d(title="Plot is being computed. This can take some seconds."),

    ),
```

So I start with an empty plot that shows my desired message. This is OK, but I would prefer to have the text a bit more eye-catching, without a plot around, that attracts attention. Is there a way to do so?

So far it is looking like this:

[image]

In holoviews there is something like that: https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Div.html#elements-bokeh-gallery-div

Comment: This is not exactly what you asked but for that purpose there is the [dcc.Loading](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/loading) component which displays a loading spinner until its children are rendered : ie. `dcc.Loading(dcc.Graph(...))`. Then in your callbacks update the loading-component's children instead of the graph figure. See also [dbc.Spinner](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/spinner/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
dcc.Graph(
        id='scatter_plot',
        figure=px.scatter_3d().add_annotation(text="Plot is being computed. This can take some seconds.", showarrow=False, font={"size":20})
)
```

Then replace figure with fully constructed 3d scatter in callback